# Copy hdfs file to another hdfs location using java

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I need to copy hdfs file to another location in hdfs using Java. The source should not be deleted, just want to copy the source file with new filename in target hdfs location.

I could see only copyFromLocal, copyToLocal or rename in FileSystem.java class.

Can anyone tell if there is any method just to copy hdfs file with new name into source directory?

Comment: what you are interested in is copyFromLocal. You found it, but you didn't read carefully what it does and how to use it

Comment: @paul.cioroianu copyFromLocal is taking source file from local system, not the HDFS location. I want to read hdfs file as source and save it in another hdfs location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **copy** function of class **FileUtil**:

From the javadoc (http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileUtil.html):

```
public static boolean copy(FileSystem srcFS,
                       Path src,
                       FileSystem dstFS,
                       Path dst,
                       boolean deleteSource,
                       boolean overwrite,
                       Configuration conf)
                throws IOException
```

Comment: Thanks, This is something i'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can always read input and save it as a new file at desired destination